# media query text not responsive

Tags: html, css, text, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using Vs and testign with chrome. Everything else is resposive but the text when I go to mobile. Here is the code if you can help me get past this hurdle. I have tried everythign I can I changed the font size from px to rem and I also adjusted the font weight . I created a div class for the text only and tried to target it by itself.

```html
<style>
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
        body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    

    /*--------------------Landing info and Image Set up-------------*/
    .wrapper {
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .landing-container{
        max-width:auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 30vh ;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top:0vh;
        background: white;
    }
    
      button {
        background-color: #8C592C;
        border: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
        width:200px;
         font-size: 20px;
       font-family: ROBOTO; 
         font-weight: 700; 
         MIN-height: 70px;
         text-decoration: NONE;
         border-radius: 20px;
     
      }

      button:hover {
  background-color: #30c2cc;
  color: #dbcb19;
}
    
     h1{
       font-family: roboto;
       font-size:2EM;
       line-height: 30px;
       FONT-WEIGHT: 600;
       color: black;
       justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    
    a.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
    
    /*--------------------Targets div to hold image-------------*/
    .land-image{
        width: 500px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        }
    
    /*--------------------Targets the actualy image within the div above-------------*/
    .land-image img{
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    
    /*--------------------Removes platform margins----------------*/
    div.grid-container.fr-view{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    
    /*--------------------Code for mobile screens @ 600px-------------*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Add media query for smaller screen sizes */
  .landing-container {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    max-width: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center; /* Add text-align center to center the image */
  }
  .land-image img {
    width: 85%; /* Change max-width to 100% to make the image full width on smaller screens */
     /* Add height auto to maintain the aspect ratio */
  }
  button {
    width: 100%; /* Change width to 100% to make the button full width on smaller screens */
  }
  .text-container {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 100;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}




    
    </style><script>
                   
    </script><!--<link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <div class="wrapper"><!--------------------Container for landing------------------>
        <div class="landing-container">
            <!--------------------Banner for landing------------------>
            <div class="land-image">
            <img src="https://classicinsurance.s3.amazonaws.com/classicinsurance.png" alt="MGE LOGO" width="500" height="AUTO" class="fr-fil fr-dib">
            <div class="text-container"><h1>"PROTECTION YOU CAN RELY ON, SERVICE YOU CAN TRUST"
                </h1></div>
            <button><a href="https://insurancetagtitle.com/classic_agency_insurance/shop/page/intropage" style="text-decoration: none;color:#002882;">
                REQUEST YOUR QUOTE</a></button></div></div></div><!--------------------End Banner for landing------------------><!--------------------End Banner for landing------------------>
```

Comment: i need help sharing the code on here

Comment: Hi, try to provide a link with https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar, or paste the code directly in the question

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Runnable code snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: @CristóbalDíazÁlvarez SO asks that code be direct in the question as external links may disappear, rendering the question useless for future readers.

Comment: You can add executable code snippets right in your question. Place your cursor in the textarea and press CTRL+M or click the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet" icon with the pointy brackets `<>` on it.